# Black mold found behind crown molding, walls and ceiling. How to remodel correctly?

Tags: hvac, insulation, mold, ventilation, water-damage

[image]I bought a 1995 manufactured home on permanent foundation, ~26’x60’ home. 2x4 exterior framing. Entire interior walls, ceiling and trim had been recently painted. Odd musty and smoker smell upon entering home. Visible nicotine stains saturated in the “accordion-style” pull-down window blinds.  Roof recently replaced; and according to neighbor, the prior roof was visibly in very bad condition.

I was replacing crown molding in master bedroom with a larger type, and found black mold. I decided to remove part of the wall, and found a lot on the back. I removed all walls and insulation in the bedroom.  Only half of the room had visible sightings of mold.  Part of ceiling was removed from exterior wall to the center peak.  Other end of the peak is the attached master bathroom, with some mold on crown molding location as well.
I decided to removed all the ceiling in the bedroom and bathroom: which will be the width of the ~26’ home.

The water source was from the bad previous roof.
To properly fix and be done with this issue, so that I can live my life without worries for myself or the next new homeowner in the many years to come… what do I need to do, for proper re-insulating the ceiling for temperature control and moisture venting, and utilizing the opportunity to improve temperature and sound insulation?
Best I can find is R-16 rockwool insulation for 2x4 walls, besides closed-cell spray foam (which I decided not to do for safety concerns if I do it wrong, and moisture venting imbalance to 1/4 section of house.

I found the edge of the roof (exterior wall sides) have one-length section of a ribbed-style styrofoam attached to the ceiling. They are 17”x40” sections for the downslope ends of the roof.  Is this for venting purposes?  Previous roof insulation was loose spray foam.  What max thickness should I use to not create any problems for moisture or venting issues?

Any and all advice much appreciated.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't see any mold in the pictures. Also can't see the spray foam insulation described

Comment: Please post a closer photo of the mold.

Comment: Spray foam - I was stating I do not want to use spray foam insulation since I don’t want to redo the entire house; it’s expense; and chance of being unlivable if it isn’t mixed properly.

Comment: I didn’t post pictures of mold originally, because I knew it was mold.  I was only wanting reference of how to address proper ventilation.  Nevertheless, I went ahead and added the pictures just in case.  These studs have been painted over with Zinsser Mold Killing Primer.